# Android - adb tools not finding device

Tags: android, adb

I just did a factory data restore so that I could use my phone for testing.

But now I am trying to use the adb tool to put a new .apk on the device using my usb, and it says device not connected.

The phone is displaying this message: MTP: server status: connecting to computer...

But it is never able to fully connect.

I tried to go to Wireless & Networks, and enable Internet pass-through, but that option is also "Turning on..." for the last 5 minutes.

Any idea why I am not able to connect?

Comment: What kind of device is it? Make sure you have the development USB settings set under Settings, Development. Also ensure it's not a USB Drive but in USB Debugging mode.

Comment: @AmitApollo thanks! The device is HTC Thunderbolt. It is about 1.5 years old.  By the way, I do not see the option for development under settings. Under which suboption is it?

Comment: What version of Android do you have on it?

Comment: @OlegVaskevich how do I actually check exactly what version I have?

Comment: You go into System Settings->About and look at "Android version".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What kind of device is it? Make sure you have the development USB settings set under Settings, Development. Also ensure it's not a USB Drive but in USB Debugging mode.

Furthermore, if it's a device driver issue, here is an article for the HTC Thunderbolt and Windows/Eclipse:
http://www.nodans.com/index.cfm/2012/2/1/Getting-USB-Device-Drivers-Working-for-HTC-Android-Development

For OSX, Motorola has a USB Link DMG, I'm not sure about HTC though.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you show give us more information, like

- What OS are you using (Windows, Mac, Ubuntu)
- Is USB debugging switched on?
- Did you restart the adb server

  ```
  $ adb kill-server
  $ sudo adb start-server
  * daemon not running. starting it now *
  * daemon started successfully *
  $ adb devices
  ```